# apache tiles: get view name inside ViewPreparer

Tags: jakarta-ee, view, tiles

I'm developing an app with tiles and I want to implement a ViewPreparer that constructs menu specific for page that is just being displayed. I can't see such thing in the [api](http://tiles.apache.org/tiles-request/apidocs/org/apache/tiles/request/class-use/Request.html). Does anyone know how to get the view name?

Comment: so far the only workaround I found is to pass an additional attribute (could be the same as the definition name) to a concrete tile view. Then you cas access it via getLocalProperties or sth like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the attribute into the xml, eg

```
<definition name="t.*" extends="t.container">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/{1}.jsp"/>
    <put-attribute name="title" expression="${song.title} - ${song.author} in ${jukebox.name}"/>
    <put-attribute name="view" value="t.{1}"/>
</definition>
```